# Mapping a simple array

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using fluent Nhibernate to map a simple class
And using Schema Generation to create this class on MySQL DB.
I can't use IList<> for my properties (I'm mapping cross-language domain classes)
So I have to use simple arrays..

I Want NHibernate to create a connection table between the two classes,
These are the domain classes:

```
    public class ClassOne
    {
        public virtual Guid Guid { get; set; }
        public virtual String Title { get; set; }
        public virtual ClassTwo[] Tags { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClassTwo
    {
        public virtual Guid Guid { get; set; }
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is the map:

```
 public class ClassOneMap : ClassMap<ClassOneMap>
    {
        public ClassOneMap ()
        {
            Id(x => x.Guid).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
            Map(x => x.Title);
            HasManyToMany(x => x.Tags)
                .Cascade.SaveUpdate());

        }
    }

    public class ClassTwoMap : ClassMap<ClassTwo>
    {
        public ClassTwoMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Guid).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
            Map(x => x.Title);
        }
    }
```

The schema generates great! It has a ClassOne, ClassTwo and ClassTwoToClassOne Tables
But when I'm trying to persist an instance of ClassOne I have an Invalid Cast exception..
This is solved by changing the arrays to IList's but I can't really do that..

Can anyone tell me how to configure the Fluent mapping to use Arrays without changing the schema architecture?

Thanks A'lot!

Comment: I'm curious, what other language are you using that doesn't allow IList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, played around this and hope that solve the question.

So models are:

```
 public class ClassOne : Entity
    {
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }

        public virtual ClassTwo[] Tags { get; set; }

     }

    public class ClassTwo : Entity
    {
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

Base class contains the Id definition which is long in my case. Should not be a problem with Guids

Mapping class: We are using FluentNhibernate with some convention, also the idea is in HasManyToMany

```
public class ClassOneMappingOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<ClassOne>
    {
        public void Override(AutoMapping<ClassOne> mapping)
        {
            mapping.HasManyToMany(x => x.Tags).AsArray(x => x.Id).ParentKeyColumn("classOneId")
                .ChildKeyColumn("classTwoId")
                .Table("ClassOneLinkClassTwo")
                .Cascade.SaveUpdate();
        }
    }
```

Please note that if you not indicate ParentKey, ChildKey and Table it will not create the link table.

The unit test which insert data looks like:

```
 public class ClassOneDataPart : DataPartBase, IDataPart
{
    public void AddToDatabase()
    {
        var classOne = new ClassOne { Title = "classOne" };

        var classTwo1 = new ClassTwo { Title = "class21" };
        var classTwo2 = new ClassTwo { Title = "class22" };

        var tags = new[] { classTwo1, classTwo2 };

        classOne.Tags = tags;

        this.SaveData(classOne);
        this.SaveData(classTwo1);
        this.SaveData(classTwo2);
    }
}
```

and the result into database is:

[image]

Regards,
Ion

Answer (score 1):

Map the collection as a private field and expose it as an array. This also makes it easy to expose AddTag and RemoveTag methods without manipulating the array.

```
public class ClassOne
{
    private IList<ClassTwo> _tags;

    public virtual Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public virtual String Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ClassTwo[] Tags
    {
        // possibly expose as method to hint that the array is re-built on every call
        get { return _tags.ToArray(); }
    }
}

public class ClassOneMap : ClassMap<ClassOne>
{
    public ClassOneMap ()
    {
        Id(x => x.Guid).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
        Map(x => x.Title);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Tags).Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use .AsArray(x=>x.Id)

Comment: Thanks but I Have already tried that.. The schema generator puts the ManyToMany table with the ClassTwo table (It holds all the data).. I Can't really figure out why..